# boost filesystem get permissions returns (509)dec == (1FD)hex. This value is not in the documentation

Tags: c++, file-permissions, boost-filesystem

Reading here [boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#file_status-constructors). The value of 509 does not exist.

The code that is doing this is:

```
boost::filesystem::path closest_existing_path = log_dir;                                                                                                                    

do {
  closest_existing_path = log_dir.parent_path();                                                                                                                            

} while (!boost::filesystem::exists(closest_existing_path) &&
    closest_existing_path != boost::filesystem::path(""));                                                                                                                  

std::cout << "Closest existing path --" << closest_existing_path <<                                                                                                         
  "-- permissions = " <<
  boost::filesystem::status(closest_existing_path).permissions() <<                                                                                                         
  std::endl;
```

The directory being passed in for sure exists.

The sample output is:

> ./logger_tester && cat results.txt
>   Closest existing path
>   --"/usr"-- permissions = 493
>   Closest existing path
>   --"/home/mehoggan/Devel/RuleSimulator/src/utils/util_tests"-- permissions = 509

Comment: Unix file permissions are normally expressed in octal, since there are three bits each for owner, group, and others. `man 2 chmod` for details.

Comment: Totally blanked on that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I do the math for you:
1FD hex = 111 111 101 bin = 0775 oct = rwxrwxr-x (user & group can read, write and execute; others can read and execute)